# Need javascript regex to allow digits, a single and specific alpha numeric character and dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

How to create a javascript regex that will allow digits, dashes, maybe even parenthesis and a single alphanumeric character, only being an 'x?'

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty basic regexp to say "match this thing or the other".

It's called "alternation", and it's represented by the vertical bar `|`.

So to match any of the characters you are asking for, we just need to write

```
/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|x|-/
```

There, you've written your first regular expression.

Now we need to say, a sequence of those things--one or more of them. To say this in regexp, we use something called a **quantifier**--you read about those, right? They're called "quantifiers" because they specify the quantity of something. Here we need the quantifier asking for one or more of something, which as you'll recall, is the plus sign `+`; you put it after the thing you want to repeat.

So we could write

```
/0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|x|-+/
```

but this won't work; it's just asking for one or more `-` characters. So to say one or more of *any* of the choices, we put the choices in a **group**, using parentheses, and put the quantifier after it:

```
/(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|x|-)+/
```

We're getting closer, except for one problem. A call such as

```
regexp.test("string")
```

will match the regexp against any portion of the string, not necessarily against the entire string. In our case, we want to make sure the **entire** string matches the regexp--in other words, contains nothing but the characters we want to allow. For that we need to use **anchors**, which you remember from your reading, right? The anchors "anchor" the match at the beginning (`^`) or end (`$`) of the string. So we write:

```
/^(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|x|-)+$/
```

In plain English: starting at the beginning of the string, match one or more of any of the alternatives, finishing at the end of the string.

However, in this case, we have a special case, where all our alternatives are single characters. For this common case, regexp offers the idea of **character set**, which I'm sure you remember from your reading. A character set gives a set of characters, any of which will match. You write it inside square brackets: `[]`. In our case, that would be:

```
[0123456789x-]
```

You'll recall that character sets also allow you to specify **ranges** of characters, using a **hyphen**, so we can simplify this to

```
[0-9x-]
```

the final hyphen doesn't create a range, because it's at the end.

There. Using alternation, groups, quantifiers, anchors, and character sets, you've written the regexp you need:

```
/^[0-9x-]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a method that passes in a key. So on keydown event in jquery I'm capturing each key stroke and doing a test. If it's not in the array of available values, JS returns false and doesn't register the key stroke.

```
    function isFaxValid(fax) {
    
        var keyCodeArray = new Array();

        keyCodeArray.push(48); //0
        keyCodeArray.push(49); //1
        keyCodeArray.push(50); //2
        keyCodeArray.push(51); //3
        keyCodeArray.push(52); //4
        keyCodeArray.push(53); //5
        keyCodeArray.push(54); //6
        keyCodeArray.push(55); //7
        keyCodeArray.push(56); //8
        keyCodeArray.push(57); //9

        keyCodeArray.push(40); //(
        keyCodeArray.push(41); //)
        keyCodeArray.push(32); //""
        keyCodeArray.push(45); //-

        $(fax).keypress(function (key) {

        if (keyCodeArray.indexOf(key.keyCode) <= -1) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

So, if anyone comes to me later on and wants something such as a "+," I'll add it.